# UITableView commitEditingStyle without deleting cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have small problem with my conception of deleting rows in UITableView. After user deletes a row i do not want to fire:

```
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
```

Instead I want to change edited cell text and background without hiding it. My approach works quite well:

> ```
> if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
>     NSMutableArray *previous_points = [self.trip_arrayOfAllPoints mutableCopy];
>     [previous_points removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
>     self.trip_arrayOfAllPoints = nil;
>
>     self.trip_arrayOfAllPoints = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[previous_points count]];
>     self.trip_arrayOfAllPoints = [previous_points mutableCopy];
>
>     self.trip_arrayOfAllPointsEDITED = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[previous_points count]];
>     self.trip_arrayOfAllPointsEDITED = [previous_points mutableCopy];
>     //[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
>
>     self.trip_isArrayOfAllPointsEDITED = YES;
> }
> ```

But after deleting a row it does not commit animation of dissapearing "DELETE" label on current cell. Is there a way around "Apple way" of deleting rows?

**EDIT - I've worked it out**

It's pretty simple and plain. Just replace deleteRowsAtIndexPaths with:

```
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

After this "delete" animation disappears and cell is still in it's place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean that "Delete" button stays, even if you pressed it? On my iOS 5.1 emulator after 
pressing "Delete" with empty:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

"Delete" button disappears.

Comment: Leave this method empty and see what is happening when you press delete. Simply /* at the beginning and */ at the end.

Comment: Thank you, after your post i've decided to leave method empty and manipulate with my cell. That solves my problem (it was just too simple) :).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this code and it's working fine

```
//self.selectedMessageIndex is NSIndexPath object declared in header file
//self.attachments is a NSMutableArray Object

[self.attachments removeObjectAtIndex:self.selectedMessageIndex.row];

[tblvAttachmentsList deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:self.selectedMessageIndex]
                                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
[tblvAttachmentsList reloadData];
```

Comment: I really do not want to commit delete animation. I just want to row to stay in place but with different color/background etc.  This is the problem.

Comment: Do we really need to use "reloadData" here? I think its not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation:.Automatic)
```

This is going to remove the delete button with a nice animation. Invoke, when you know you are not going to delete the row:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle:UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {

        //An action happens here. If it was successful, page is refreshed
        //If the action fails, cell stays. I am showing an error and:
        self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation:.Automatic)
    }
}
```